# Time complexity to insert a node at the end of circular linked list?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

Time complexity to insert a node at the end of circular singly linked list containing N elements ? Suppose I have pointer to the first node.

---

I think that it is O(N) as I have to parse the LL to the node before the new node to modify its next field.

Have I got it right ?

Comment: Is the list single-linked? If it is, your answer is correct. It's possible to solve it in `O(1)` for a double linked list, though.

Comment: Another trick is to have a pointer to the last node instead of the first. This way you can insert in O(1) both at the end and at the front.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the end of a circular singly linked list can be done in **O(1)** time.

1. Create a new node and insert it after your head node.
2. Copy your data from head into this new node.
3. Add your new data into the old head node.
4. Re-assign head.

As these are all constant time operations, this procedure is O(1).